# MySQL complex join of three tables

Tags: mysql, sql, join

I have three tables, a users table, courses table, and hidden courses table.

The hidden courses table includes a `user_id` column and `course_id` column.

Let's say I want to see all the hidden courses table information for all users for the course 'course1'. When I get my data, I want it to include:

- hidden_courses.id
- courses.id
- courses.title
- user.id
- user.name

I have been trying a few things to perform this query, but it doesn't always fill my columns properly. I want the course information to always be from 'course1' and a list of all the users. The only thing that may not exist is the `hidden_courses.id`.

Here is what I was trying:

```
SELECT hc.id, u.id, u.name, c.id, c.title
FROM hidden_courses AS hc
RIGHT JOIN users AS u ON u.id = hc.user_id
RIGHT JOIN courses AS c ON c.id = hc.course_id
```

Should I perform the query using LEFT JOINS instead and select from the users table? I wasn't successful with that either.

There is no relation between the courses and users table. Lets say I have 3 users, and one hidden course record for user1 and course1. I would want the output to be:

[image]

Comment: Believe me, this doesn't qualify as "complex". :-)

Comment: What's the relation between `users` and `courses`?

Comment: If you provide your table structures, some sample data, and expected output given that sample data then it would be much easier to answer. Please see: http://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask

Comment: As to whether or not the `JOIN`s are complex, that's a matter of opinion. For someone who has been working with SQL for a long time this might not seem complex. For someone who just learned what a `SELECT` statement is last week it could be incredibly complex.

Comment: There is no relation between the users and courses table. The only thing really linking them is the hidden_courses table.

Comment: @TomH Not really. If we imagine that there is a spectrum of join complexity, then this has to be at the start of it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I generally find `LEFT JOIN`s to be easier to understand.

```
SELECT hc.id, u.id, u.name, c.id, c.title
FROM courses as c -- must exist
LEFT JOIN users as u on 1=1 -- all users, optional
LEFT JOIN hidden_courses as hc on hc.user_id=u.id and hc.course_id=c.id -- optional
```

Supposing there are no users, then do you want no results? If so then substitute `LEFT JOIN users` with `JOIN users` and then you get that effect.

Do you want to filter to only users part of the main `courses c`? If so, substitute `1=1` with something that ties the `users` to their corresponding `courses`.

I do not know if this is possible with `RIGHT JOIN` as I never use them.